# How to Transform Emails in Hanami to include inline the styles defined in an external css file?

Tags: ruby, hanami

If I use roadie/premailer to transform my emails in Hanami, then where should I place the transformation code in Hanami?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which works:

In the gemfile:

```
gem 'roadie', '~> 3.4'
```

And assuming that we put the style in the: **lib/app/mailers/assets/stylesheets/mail.css** the prepare method of the email:

```
html_part = mail.html_part
old_html = html_part.body.decoded

document = Roadie::Document.new old_html
document.add_css File.read( File.join(Hanami.root, "lib", "app", "mailers", "assets", "stylesheets", "mail.css"))
new_html = document.transform

html_part.body = new_html
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a more general question about email CSS inlining. You can check this gem: https://github.com/premailer/premailer

Comment: I've used that gem in my projects :)

The question was, where to put the transformation code in Hanami if I use premailer/roadie

Comment: Did you try to alter the `mail` object via `prepare`? It's a hook that is executed before to deliver the email. See https://github.com/hanami/mailer#attachments